# ¿Qué propósito tiene el acento en una pregunta? (dónde, qué, cuándo, etc.)

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, acentuación, escritura

He aprendido palabras como `donde`, `cuando`, `que` y `como` que se escribe sin acento en algunos casos.

Pero se escribe esas palabras (y otras más) con acento cuando están usadas en una pregunta y algunos otros tipos de frases.

Ejemplos:

> Cuando viene la noche, está oscuro afuera. ***(sin acento)***
>
> ¿Cuándo vas a tu casa? ***(con acento)***

---

> Como era tarde, traté de dormir. ***(sin acento)***
>
> ¿Cómo le va, amigo? ***(con acento)***

---

> Donde el va, yo no quiero ir. ***(sin acento)***
>
> ¿Dónde pasa el carro? ***(con acento)***

¿Por qué se escribe preguntas así?

¿Se lee diferente la pregunta sin acento, o tal vez esas palabras tienen otro significado en una pregunta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifica la pronunciación de las palabras dentro de una oración.  Bajo la nueva ortografía (2010), las únicas palabras que existen en dos variantes con o sin tilde, aunque con la misma sílaba acentuada, son las palabras que existen en una forma no acentuada (átona) y una acentuada (tónica).

Las variantes sin tilde son las que no llevan el acento prosódico.  Estas, siendo átonas, se adjuntan a otras palabras sí acentuadas durante la pronunciación y no existen independiente de las otras.  Por ejemplo, si digo, «te lo diré», la pronunciación es como si fuera una palabra entera «telodiré».  Pero digo «tráeme un té», la pronunciación sale «tráeme unté» (los artículos también carecen de acento prosódico y se juntan con el adjetivo o sustantivo que les sigue).

En tus ejemplos, podemos verlo, que se pronuncian como tales:

> cuandoviéne lanóche, está oscúro afuéra <sub>(sin tilde, *cuandoviene* se pronuncia más como una palabra que como dos)</sub>
>
> cuándo vás atucása
>
> Comoéra tárde, traté dedormír
>
> cómo levá, amígo
>
> dondél va, yo noquiéro ír.
>
> dónde pása elcárro

Como has adivinado, las palabras son diferentes.  Cuando es una palabra tónica (con tilde), es una interrogativa que reemplaza un lugar desconocido, si no, es un relativo que inicia una cláusula nueva describiendo un sitio conocido.  Las formas sin tilde nunca se acentúan en el habla normal, las formas con tilde siempre.

Comment: Ahh, esto me aclara mucho el asunto. Yo (y me imagino que todas las demás personas que acostumbramos poner las tildes) siempre pensé que se trataba de una "tradición". Pero ahora veo que hay un fundamento gramatical, incluso semántico.

Comment: (Curiosamente, parece que la forma monosilábica —y arcaico/real— de *nosotros* (*nos*) no lleva tilde, a pesar de ser tónica en contraste al *nos* de los pronombres átonos que van con los verbos.)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces preguntas

> - qué,
> - cómo,
> - quién,
> - cuándo,
> - dónde,
> - por qué,
> - para qué,

llevan tilde para denotar que son preguntas.

> - ¿Cómo te llamas?
> - ¿Qué haces?
> - ¿Cuándo nos vamos?

Aún cuando las preguntas sean implícitas,

> - No se cuándo vamos a ir a comprar.
> - Investiga cómo se llama.

Comment: No obstante la respuesta anterior, sería bueno recordar que "cómo" con acento significa "what" o bien "how" "¿ cómo te llamas ?" "no sé cómo resolver  ese problema"; "como" sin acento significa like "soy como tú = i am like you"; que "que" sin acento significa "that" "pienso que es verdad" y que "qué" con acento significa "what" :  "¿ qué hora es ?" ; "¡ Qué escándalo !" y que ello no depende en absoluto de que la frase sea interogativa o no, para estos dos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy simple, es por el mero hecho de como se pronuncian.

Donde las palabras llevan el acento (Que en realidad se llaman tilde), suenan más fuerte, o con especial énfasis.

> *Que tontería...*

Por ejemplo ahí el **que**, no tiene especial énfasis.

> *¿Qué decís?*

En esté **que** sí se pronuncia más fuerte en la e, al hacer una pregunta.

> *¡Que te calles!*

Y en esté ultimo son los signos de exclamación los que determinan el énfasis, en esté caso, es toda la frase la que se dice con énfasis.